# Defining a string with variables in Spring xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, jakarta-ee

I need to define a String path with variables in Spring XML which is to be passed to another class as Constructor argument.

I tried two things, both didnt work:

Method 1:

```
<bean id="someBean" class="aClass">
    <constructor-arg value="${config.base}/test.properties"/>
    <constructor-arg value="6000"/>
</bean>
```

Method 2:

```
<bean id="test" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="${config.base}/test.properties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="someBean" class="aClass">
    <constructor-arg ref="test"/>
    <constructor-arg value="6000"/>
</bean>
```

The value for path comes as "${config.base}/test.properties" in both cases. How should i define this path to be constructed with ${config.base}?

**Note that this variable is properly used in other places and working fine. ex:**

```
 <util:properties id="properties" location="${config.base}/default.properties"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the rest of your context and how you load it.

Comment: Only couple of other beans have been defined in this context file. The project is packaged as war and deployed in tomcat. In tomcat catalina.properties, config.base variable has been defined. This is the setup. As i mentioned, this variable works in other places but when defining constructor argument, the values is taken as given without replacing variables.

Comment: Are the beans and `util:properties` in the same context? Where is the property placeholder configurer defined?

Comment: Yes but this value is not from property file. This is defined in tomcat catalina.properties and accessed as application level variable. So no property placeholder configuration for this. just ${config.base} should be enough and works too except for constructor argument.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. I can't reproduce this based on the things you've shown.

Comment: IF you already have a spring web app running in tomcat, could you please add a property in tomcat catalina.properties and create a spring bean of Class String using that property? (As shown in the question). I would like to know whether it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how it worked in one place and not in the other one. But, adding

```
<context:property-placeholder />
```

solved this problem.

Comment: That is what I meant by a property placeholder configurer. That's what that tag registers.